# Laravel 5.6 - request() with 2 variables

Tags: laravel-5, request

I am filtering results via request()->variable. When there is only one variable the view comes back as it should eg.../products/summer, displaying only products that belong to a certain season.

What i'm trying to do is call in a second variable /products/summer?product_category=shirts displaying the season products as above while filtering those that belong to a specific category (eg.shirts).

This is my controller part:

```
public function index()
    {
      if (request()->season) {
        $products = Product::with('seasons')->whereHas('seasons', function ($query){
        $query->where('slug', request()->season);
      })->get();
        $product_categories = ProductCategory::with('seasons')->whereHas('seasons', function ($query){
        $query->where('slug', request()->season);
      })->get();
        $season = Season::where('slug', request()->season)->firstOrFail();



      } **elseif (request()->product_category)** {
        $products = Product::with('product_categories')->whereHas('product_categories', function ($query){
        $query->where('slug', request()->product_category);
      })->get();
        $product_categories = ProductCategory::with('seasons')->get();
        $season = Season::where('slug', request()->season)->first();

}......

return view('season')->with([
        'products' => $products,
        'product_categories' => $product_categories,
        'season' => $season,



      ]);
```

Is there a way to include season and product_category in the elseif above so that it corresponds to summer?product_category=shirts ?

My nav link passes this:

```
href="{{ route ('season.index',['season' => $season->slug, 'product_category' => $product_category->slug])}}"
```

The route is:

```
Route::get('/products/{season?}', 'SeasonController@index')->name('season.index');
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I did not understand exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand exactly what you need
If this code was not useful,plese explan more and i  change it:

my view :

```
<a
href="{{ route ('season.index',['season' =>$season->slug, 'product_category' => $product_category->slug])}}"
>send</a>
```

my route :

```
Route::get('/products', 'SeasonController@index')->name('season.index');
```

`SeasonController` controler :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SeasonController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->get('season'))
        {
            # do something

        }elseif($request->get('product_category'))
        {
            # do something
        }
        else
        {
            # do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What i'm trying to get is the season and the product category in one request so that it can be called as products/summer?product_category=shirts . (In other words, concatenate season&product_category)